# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "6283201d60c794631cd1ba33\n" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, get, httprequest

I'm working on a social media project and getting this getting when I'm sending like/Unlike post request

**CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "6283\n" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"
at model.Query.exec (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4639:21)
at model.Query.Query.then (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4738:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
messageFormat: undefined,
stringValue: '"6283\n"',
kind: 'ObjectId',
value: '6283\n',
path: '_id',
reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of
24 hex characters or an integer
at new BSONTypeError (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
at new ObjectId (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:66:23)      at castObjectId (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
at ObjectId.cast (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:247:12)
at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1135:12)
at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1567:15)
at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1557:15)
at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1534:20)
at cast (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:336:32)

at model.Query.Query.cast (E:\social-media-app-mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5062:12),
valueType: 'string'
}**

routes :

```
const express = require("express");
const { createPost, likeAndUnlikePost } = require("../controllers/post");
const { isAuthenticated } = require("../middlewares/auth");

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/post/:id").get(isAuthenticated, likeAndUnlikePost);

module.exports = router;
```

models:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  caption: String,
  image: {
    public_id: String,
    url: String,
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  likes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
      comment:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
      }
    },
  ],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

likeAndUnlikePost:

```
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Post not found",
      });
    }

    if (post.likes.includes(req.user._id)) {
      const index = post.likes.indexOf(req.user._id);

      post.likes.splice(index, 1);

      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Post Unliked",
      });
    } else {
      post.likes.push(req.user._id);

      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Post Liked",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
    console.error(error)  }
};
```

Comment: 6283201d60c794631cd1ba33\n, here \n is unnecessary, please check from where you are getting this. This error usually occurs when MongoDB expects a certain type of data but gets some other type, here MongoDB is expecting ObjectId but getting string.

Comment: @AnveegSinha How do I convert Sting to ObjectId??

Comment: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('YOURSTRINGVARIABLE');

Comment: I still think your issue is because of the extra \n at the end of the id, can you please add the frontend part of the code in this question too?

Answer (score 2):

First verify if the _id exists. Then try converting the _id which is string, to ObjectId like

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

when i encounterd this error it was because i was using the get method instead of the post method

Comment: Question says  CastError. In your case, the error was probably a routing error

Answer (score 0):

### Alright my friend, I see the problem!

Unlike the other answers, I actually ran your code.
Seems like it's working just fine as it is.
You don't need to change a thing in it!!!
One issue though,
look at the error you got:

`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "6283\n"`

What is this value of "6283\n"?  **That's the problem!**
It seems like you have a user with an id of "6283\n".
Which means, it contains *numbers* AND a *white-space*, so the white-space makes it as string.
So, while I said that there is NO problem with your code, there might be a problem with your *User Model*, which you haven't shown us in this thread.

### The Answer - How to fix it

Because I haven't seen your User Model, I'll make 2 guesses:

1. You wanted/intended your User _id field to be of type ObjectId. If so, find out why you have a user with a weird _id value of "6283\n", cause basically it's two mistakes: A) Your _id is made up of numbers, i.e. Number type, while wanting ObjectId type. B) You got a **100% accidental space** that slipped inside there. Find out how it got there.
2. You wanted/intended your User _id field to be of type Number. If so, then this again splits into two problems: A) Your user _id still contains a white-space, which is what I assume **100% accidental**. Find out its source. B) Your user _id is made up of numbers, which is what you want, but look at the array field inside your Post model, which contains a ref to your user. You state there that the User's _id field is of type **ObjectId**, and not a **Number**, hence the mismatch.

Answer (score -2):

Somewhere in your code you have assigned string value to `_id` (which is of type `ObjectId`)